# Jump lines on pst-pdgr

Tags: pstricks

I have a pedigree like this:

[image]

I want to have these bumps where lines cross:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this with pstricks?

Thanks, B

Edit: MWE https://www.overleaf.com/read/gggnbpzfqgnz

Comment: Please provide a corresponding minimal working example (MWE) for us to work on.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-6,-6)(6,6)
\psline(0,0.1)(5,0.1)       
\psline(0,-0.1)(5,-0.1)     
\psline(0,1.1)(5,1.1)       
\psline(0,0.9)(5,0.9)       
\psline(0,4.1)(5,4.1)       
\psline(0,3.9)(5,3.9)       
\pscustom{
    \psline(1,5)(1,4.2)
    \psarcn(1,4){0.2}{90}{-90}
    \psline(1,3.8)(1,1.2)
    \psarcn(1,1){0.2}{90}{-90}
    \psline(1,0.8)(1,0.2)
    \psarcn(1,0){0.2}{90}{-90}
    \psline(1,-0.2)(1,-1)
}
\end{pspicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible to write an own macro for such lines, like

```
 \specialLine(xStart,yStart)(L1)(L2)...(Ln)(xEnd,yEnd)
```

Comment: Thanks, lines are drawn by pst-pdgr and not by hand. I need to find a way if the lines cross and maybe implement such macro instead of ncline command that pst-pdgr using by default

Comment: sure, I showed only how the default line has to be modified ...